# Issue about JavaScript scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have some question about `scrollTop`, I have set `$(window).scrollTop(150);` inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`. When page is refresh , page have scroll down for `150`, BUT when page is load done, page scroll up to `0` automatically. I not understand why this happen, if I doing it wrong, please tell me, Thanks.

Comment: I just tried with a little example.. seems to work fine. does the javascript console have any output?

Comment: Has your page a scrollbar when the document is ready? Maybe you are doing a scroll top first and the additional content is being loaded after that. Try with something like setTimeout(do150ScrollFunction,2000); to check if is an issue regarding to loading time.

Comment: @ChrisK. no error. I also tried in jsfiffle , it look it same https://jsfiddle.net/t8w1ybu8/1/

Comment: @Polak can you be more specific about setTimeout(do150ScrollFunction,2000);

Comment: That's a good idea, @ImHappy . You could alternatively add a 'console.log($(window).height());' to your document.ready function. then check console output how high it is

Comment: I have updated your fiddle with jquery, so it actually works now https://jsfiddle.net/t8w1ybu8/3/

Comment: @ImHappy something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ds38aj5n/1/ just to test in your code because it works in jsfiddle, so, I think we would need more information to know what is going on.